# Check “Correct Aspect” Option

Tags: uv

I cannot locate the Correct Aspect option in my Blender 2.82 Version.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Cannot replicate the issue, works just fine on my end. Would restarting Blender help?

Comment: Hi Jachym. Yes I quit and restarted Blender, and it appeared.

Thank you.